# Footer component isn't placed correctly

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have an `AppLayout` component which has:

1. A `div` with the `h-full` utility class, to make it take the full page height.
2. A `Background` component to make a background with blur. It has three main elements:

   - `Navbar`
   - `Outlet`, which dynamically changes height
   - `Footer`

```js
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Background from '../components/Background';
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import NewNavbar from '../components/NewNavbar';

export const AppLayout = () => (
    <div className='h-full'>
        <Background>
            <div className='min-h-full backdrop-blur-2xl flex flex-col'>
                <div>
                    <NewNavbar />
                </div>
                <div className='flex-auto'>
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
                <div className=''>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Background>
    </div>
);
```

As you see, I applied `flex flex-col` to my "wrapper" div and `flex-auto` to a div wrapping my `Outlet` component, but this is not working. When I use straight HTML and CSS, the footer is placed correctly at the bottom of the page, and it always works.

Answer (score 0):

All was so simple.

```
export const AppLayout = () => (
    <div className='h-full'>
        <Background >
            <div className='min-h-screen backdrop-blur-2xl flex flex-col'>
                <div>
                    <NewNavbar />
                </div>
                <div className='flex-auto'>
                    <Outlet />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Background>
    </div>
);
```

Replace the min-h-full to min-h-screen